# React Router v4 + Regex don't like Template Literals

Tags: ecmascript-6, react-router, template-literals

React Router 4.0.0 comes with **Regex** to validate the querystring parameters.
However, it does not seem compatible with ES6 Template Literals.

Here is a very simple example :

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route Route path={routeConstant} component={MyComponent} />
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you try with the following values, you'll see that the first 2 constants work, but the third does not.

```
const root = 'folder'
const routeConstant1 = '/folder/:id(\d+)'  // <= /folder/21 matches
const routeConstant2 = `/${root}/:id`      // <= /folder/21 matches
const routeConstant3 = `/${root}/:id(\d+)` // <= /folder/21 does not match
```

There is probably a very good explanation (there always is), but I'd really appreciate a few pointers because that feels a bit confusing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I posted that question too fast I guess.

The answer is in the way Template Literals work :
[ECMAScript 6 - Template Literals](http://es6-features.org/#RawStringAccess)

=> "backslashes are not interpreted"

So the solution to have routeConstant3 work is simply to write it like this :

```
const routeConstant3 = `/${root}/:id(\\d+)`
```

Comment: It knows /folder/21 but  /folder/21abc should be an invalid route, which is where this check fails and react router attempts to render invalid route.